# How to override laravel filament vendor method/function

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-filament, filamentphp

I am using Laravel with FilamentPhp and as per requirements I changes default "name" to "username" in my migration and when I login I am getting errors because I changed name to username and If I update the name to username in vendor filamentmanager.php then It's working but it's bad practise

`Filament\FilamentManager::getUserName(): Return value must be of type string, null returned`

How can I override that function from this

```
public function getUserName(Model | Authenticatable $user): string
    {
        if ($user instanceof HasName) {
            return $user->getFilamentName();
        }

        return $user->getAttributeValue('name');
    }
```

to this

```
public function getUserName(Model | Authenticatable $user): string
    {
        if ($user instanceof HasName) {
            return $user->getFilamentName();
        }

        **return $user->getAttributeValue('username');**
    }
```

Please advice, I tried creating custom service provide but not succeed.

Comment: extend the filamentmanager.php class and make your changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filament did that for you, there's no need to override anything.

Custom behavior can be achieved with the help of below lines of core code:

```php
if ($user instanceof HasName) {
    return $user->getFilamentName();
}
```

This means Filament checks whether your model implements that interface. If implemented, it will use the interface method to return a custom value instead of the default name column.

First, your User model class needs to implement `HasName` interface, then you must implement the interface's method to return your desired value.

Here's an example:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

// use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Filament\Models\Contracts\HasName;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable implements HasName
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'username',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
        'password' => 'hashed',
    ];

    public function getFilamentName(): string
    {
        return $this->getAttributeValue('username');
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

a custom service provider

```
php artisan make:provider CustomFilamentServiceProvider
```

register custom provider using `config/app.php`

```
'providers' => [
    App\Providers\CustomFilamentServiceProvider::class,
],
```

then override the method

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Filament\FilamentManager;

class CustomFilamentServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        
    }

    public function boot()
    {
        $this->app->extend(FilamentManager::class, function ($manager) {
            $manager->macro('getUserName', function ($user) {
                if ($user instanceof HasName) {
                    return $user->getFilamentName();
                }

                return $user->getAttributeValue('username');
            });

            return $manager;
        });
    }
}
```

then clear cache

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

Comment: Nope, not working